# Vectorizing for loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

In MATLAB, vectorized code is faster than using for-loops. I have been trying to do this but I do not fully understand how this works. I was hoping someone could show me how to improve these 2 for loops and a while loop with changing indices so I could get my head round it. Any help would be a amazing.

```
width= 700;
height= 600;
fg= zeros(height, width);
for i= 1: height
    for j= 1: width
        fg(i, j) = 0;
        while ((match== 0)&& (k<= M))
            if (w(i, j, rank_ind(k))>= thresh)
                if (abs(u_diff(i, j, rank_ind(k)))<= D* sd(i, j, rank_ind(k)))
                    fg(i, j)= 0;
                    match= 1;
                else
                    fg(i, j)= fr_bw(i, j); 
                end
            end
            k= k+ 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Note `w`, `u_diff`, `sd`, `rank_ind` and `fr_b` are all arrays

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions: [MATLAB Vectorizing for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820229/matlab-vectorizing-for-loops). Instead, you should edit the original question to better reflect your problem.

Comment: I have re posted the last question was confusing and the code was incorrect I have flagged to be removed and re posted with the correct code so it can be understood.

Comment: @user729506: You could've edited your previous question to make it clearer. If you feel the previous question cannot be salvaged by editing, then you can delete it yourself, and pause to think how you can improve the question before posting it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see whether I understand you correctly: You want to copy the value of `fr_bw` into `fg` only if no corresponding value in `u_diff` is smaller than `D*sd`, and `w` is above some threshold, right?

In this case, you can rewrite your code the following way:

```
%# find where u_diff is larger than D*sd
%# but not where there's any u_diff that is smaller than D*sd
whereToCopy = any( w(:,:,rank_ind) >= thresh  & ...
  abs(u_diff(:,:,rank_ind)) > D*sd(:,:,rank_ind),3) & ...
  ~any( w(:,:,rank_ind) >= thresh  & ...
  abs(u_diff(:,:,rank_ind)) <= D*sd(:,:,rank_ind),3);

%# whereToCopy has 1 wherever we need to copy, and 0 elsewhere
%# thus, create fg from fr_bw directly by multiplication
fg = double(fr_bw) .* double(whereToCopy);
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, this could be a very silly problem but I implemented you code, thank you, but it returned an error: Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles. This error appeared on the line fg = fr_bw.* whereToCopy, on the times. Have I missed something silly sorry?

Comment: @user729506: yes, you missed telling me that `fr_bw` is not a double. Now it should work.

Comment: My apologise it still does not work but I think it is because I use the rgb2gray function which fr_bw holds. fr_bw = rgbgray(fr).

Comment: @user729506: Ok, this might help then.